# MVC framework unit testing java

Tags: java, unit-testing, model-view-controller, junit

My task is to create `Unit Testing` for the MVC frame work. I tried to search it on google but instead of just MVC, what i see is for Spring MVC.
I have some idea on basic syntax of the JUnit Testing 
 I'm new to unit testing so i only know that much. 
So please can you give me a sample on how to Unit Test an MVC. Do i really have to setup `Required Dependencies with Maven`?

**UPDATE:**

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginController
 */
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * Determines the version number for this serializable class.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginController() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String username = request.getParameter( SessionUtility.USERNAME );
        String password = request.getParameter( SessionUtility.PASSWORD );
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        boolean withError = false;

        if( request.getParameter( RegistrationController.UPDATE_PASSWORD_BUTTON ) != null &&
            request.getParameter( RegistrationController.UPDATE_PASSWORD_BUTTON ).equalsIgnoreCase( "updatepass" ) )
        {
            String userId = request.getParameter( "userid" );
            String newPassword = request.getParameter( "newpassword" );
            String oldPassword = request.getParameter( "oldpassword" );

            UsersDAO userDAO = new UsersDAO();

            if( userDAO.isUserPasswordMatch( userId, oldPassword ) )
            {
                userDAO.setNewPassword( newPassword, userId );
                request.getSession().setAttribute( ProntoUtility.SUCCESS_MESSAGE, "Password successfully updated." );
            }
            else
            {
                request.setAttribute( ProntoUtility.ERROR_MESSAGE, "Old password did not match." );
            }
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.STATE_TABLE_DISPLAY );
            try
            {
                rd.forward( request, response );
            }
            catch( ServletException e )
            {

                log.error( "ServletException" );
            }
            catch( IOException e )
            {

                log.error( "IOException" );
            }
            return;
        }
        else if( session.getAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_NAME ) != null )
        {
            session.getAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_TYPE );
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.STATE_TABLE_DISPLAY );

            withError = true;
        }
        else if( ( username == null || password == null ) && !withError )
        {
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.LOGIN_PAGE );
            withError = true;
        }
        else if( ( username == "" || password == "" ) && !withError )
        {
            request.setAttribute( ProntoUtility.ERROR_MESSAGE, "Please fill-up the required fields." );
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.LOGIN_PAGE );
            withError = true;
        }
        else if( !withError )
        {

            String encryptedPassword =  PasswordEncryption.encryptPassword(password);

            UsersDAO usersDAO = new UsersDAO();
            UsersModel login = usersDAO.getUsernamePassword( username, encryptedPassword );

            if( login != null )
            {

                String usernameDB = login.getUsername();
                String passwordDB = login.getPassword();
                String teamId = login.getTeamId();
                String userName = login.getUsername();
                int userId = login.getUserId();

                if( usernameDB.equals( username ) && passwordDB.equals( encryptedPassword ) )
                {
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.USERNAME, userName );
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_TEAM, teamId );
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_ID, userId );
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_NAME, usernameDB );
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_TYPE, login.getType() );
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_PROJECT, login.getProjectId() );
                    session.setAttribute( SessionUtility.SESSION_PROJECT_NAME, login.getProjectName() );

                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.STATE_TABLE_DISPLAY );
                    withError = true;
                }
                else if( !withError )
                {
                    request.setAttribute( ProntoUtility.ERROR_MESSAGE, "Incorrect username/password." );
                    rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.LOGIN_PAGE );
                    withError = true;
                }
            }
            else if( !withError )
            {
                request.setAttribute( ProntoUtility.ERROR_MESSAGE, "Incorrect username/password." );
                rd = request.getRequestDispatcher( ProntoUtility.LOGIN_PAGE );
                withError = true;

            }
        }

        try
        {
            if( withError == true )
            rd.forward( request, response );
        }
        catch( ServletException e )
        {
            log.debug( "Unable to forward to requested dispatcher", e );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            log.debug( "Null forward request", e );
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
     *      javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
     */
    @Override
    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse )
    {
        doGet( paramHttpServletRequest, paramHttpServletResponse );
    }
}
```

I added a sample controller of the project i'm working on.

Comment: If you use Google you can use "-spring" to tell Google to return pages without "spring".

Comment: @sjngm i tried to search using "-spring" but it seems there is still no tutorial for making unit testing for the MVC framework. How do i UnitTest a controller? do i have to relate it to the model and view while i do the testing?

Comment: It would be worth posting some pared down code examples showing the code you are looking to test - although the MVC pattern is well established and (when implemented well) does support good unit testing, different people interpret the pattern differently and therefore there is no 'one size fits all' solution to testing an implementation of MVC.

Comment: @robjohncox I updated the post. Please check.

Comment: MVC is a design pattern. What you have there is a servlet not "an MVC". You want to unit-test a servlet.

Comment: @JBNizet if a pasted a servlet controller and a view there. Will you read it all?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It's too long to read if i pasted all the codes of the view, well the model is simple but if i posted the whole MVC here for the login, it will also mean that i have to paste the DAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to use junit to make unit tests?**

If you say yourself now: "But I want to test MVC, not learn how unit tests work in theory" then here is the reply:

Unit testing means to test a single class or unit (in Java it's a class) without any interference by other classes. Of course an application has more than one class and they use each other. But with [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) you can give the tested class objects, that just provide the necessary things the class needs, but are not objects of the class the tested class uses on runtime. The mock objects just look and feel like real objects. You specify exactly what values they shall return on what method calls.

That way you can test a single class without any other class interfering. Problems can be thereby easily detected (just one possible source). Usually you write one unit test case for each class.

As this is a per-class solution, it is basically unimportant which framework you use. But some frameworks support testing (are completely unit-tested, support dependency injection) whereas others do not (e.g. a lot of singletons).

**How can I test the given class?**

Well write a JUnit Test Case (good IDE supports you with that) for a single class only. If this class extends another class that is *not* your code than this is as easy as writing a test for a class with only Object as parent. You don't have to test the parent's methods, just your own.
Ideally the constructor has no side-effects. It just initializes an object into a stable state but does not start other actions. That way you can even unit test classes that extend class within your own codebase. As the parent classes are only used for the constructor (and maybe some method calls within your class), you can concentrate testing the methods of the subclass.

As you write a unit test for every of your classes, so do you for the parent class. If problems are in the parent class, the related test case will find it out (if written well).

Coming back to your question: First there is nothing as testing an MVC. MVC is a design pattern. Second in unit tests you don't test the interaction of classes (look for functional tests).

**Functional tests**

Functional tests do test the interaction of a certain subset of components. One functional test could test the login in a CMS. For one login there are needed a multitude of classes. In the testing timeline, you first run unit tests and then functional tests (as these require working classes). Whenever something doesn't work, you have to rerun the procedure after you fixed the problems.

**Summary**

You asked for a sample to test "an MVC". As explained earlier there is nothing as testing an MVC as it's a pattern. As the shown servlet has one gigantic method (no comment on how well structured that is -- or not is) and one method that just calls it, it isn't build very test friendly. In addition the method is protected so you would need to make a [white-box test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) as opposed to [black-box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).

A functional test may be interesting for you as that would allow you to actually use multiple classes and test their interaction. If your class for example does XYZ and changes the settings of class B, then you can test the interaction by calling the method of your class and then compare the expected result with the actual setting of class B.

With the given code alone a working test sample is not really practical.